# SQLI/PHP: Column $get working but not sorting?

Tags: php, mysqli

The first section code should be correct as the url changes when you click a column:

```
$sort="";
$order='id';
$records=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER by $order $sort");

if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC';
    $sort = ($sort == 'ASC') ? 'DESC': 'ASC';
    debug_to_console( "Get_sort triggered");
} else{ 
    $sort='asc';
}

if(isset($_GET['order'])){
    $order = $_GET['order'];
    debug_to_console( "Get_order triggered");
}
```

There is a good chance the error might be in this second part?

```
 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['position']; ?> </td>
    <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $row['date']; ?> </td>
    <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $row['updated']; ?> </td>
    <td>
    <a href="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="edit" class="button green_btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </a>
    <a href="index.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="del" class="button del_btn" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a>
    </td>

    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

EDIT: There is no error (as far as I am aware). Just nothing sorts by $order. Instead, the table simply stays the same and orders by id.

1. Try1: Putting $order and $sort at the end causes the $sort to not
   work on top within the URL.
2. Try2: Putting id="" causes a parameter
   error.

Putting $order and $sort like this below causes the whole table to not work.

```
    $order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'id';
    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC';

    $sort = ($sort == 'ASC') ? 'DESC': 'ASC';

    $records=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER by $order $sort");
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error that I know of but I will double check. When you click the column, nothing happens. But the URL will change from asc/desc and the order="order" will also update.

Comment: `$sort = ($sort == 'ASC') ? 'DESC': 'ASC';` This just inverses the sort direction. Is this inteded?

Comment: In the first code block you're setting the `$order` and `$sort` variables *after* you do the query. Shouldn't it be the other order?

Comment: I think I tried switching the order but nothing happened. I will try again. Good idea.

Comment: `mysqli_error($con)` shows what exactly?

Comment: I have no error. Nothing just sorts. The column will sort by id not the "$order".

Answer (score 3):

You are executing your query before determining the value for $sort.

Comment: Why would error reporting show anything? He initialized the variables to default values.

Comment: Beside `$sort`, `$order` is not initialized correctly as well.

Comment: But $sort is changing in the URL from asc/desc : desc/asc. I tried putting $sort on the bottom but then $sort does not work at all (it is blank). 

Or I could be confused and need more clarification.

Comment: @ScottSchmidt You just need to move the query to the bottom.'

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

First, you're doing the query before you set `$order` and `$sort` based on the `$_GET` parameters. You need to move the query to the bottom.

Second, you're setting `$order` to the opposite of what the parameter says.

Also, to prevent SQL-injection, you should validate the `order` parameter.

```
$sort="";
$order='id';

if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC';
    $sort = ($sort == 'ASC') ? 'ASC': 'DESC';
    debug_to_console( "Get_sort triggered");
} else{ 
    $sort='asc';
}

if(isset($_GET['order'])){
    $valid_order = array('id', 'name', 'dept');
    $order = in_array($_GET['order'], $valid_order) ? $_GET['order'] : 'id';
    debug_to_console( "Get_order triggered");
} 

$records=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER by $order $sort");
```

Comment: Interesting. Prior to reading this I tried a very similar solution but forgot one simple line on top. Our solution half worked but I think the $sort is sending the info to the URL. I will try a couple different things. Plus1 for the help thanks